# Record and playback input/movement accurate on games running on different frame rates

Tags: game-engine, frame-rate, timing, timedelta, keyframe

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out the solution to.
I want to record the input in a game and play the input back afterward. I save the input every frame.
But when recording and playing the input back. The framerate isn't the same. That leads to that the playback isn't played back accurately.

So my question is. How can you save a timestamp that can be accurately replayed back without the frame rate being the exact same?
Let's say you have a game that runs at 60 fps. And you record the input. But now the game runs at 30 fps. How can you playback the input so it will be the same?

I guess we can calculate the game frame time/deltatime and use that. But I am not good at math so I haven't figured out how to implement it to fit my use case.